# GTK_IM_MODULE=xim breaks dead keys in GTK and QT applications

Tags: xkb, compose-key, dead-keys

I'm using `XIM` to have the compose key take into account my `~/.XCompose` file (it's the only input method that takes it into account, all the others I tried use hard-coded tables). However, it is breaking the dead keys in GTK and QT application: If in `charmap` (GTK) I press <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>, it just prints `a`. The <kbd>^</kbd> key is recognized though, as it makes the caret stop blinking while I'm pressing it. In `kate` (QT), it prints `^a` instead (two separate characters).

**How can I make dead keys work when using `XIM`?**

---

Here are the relevant environment variables:

```
$ env | grep '\(IM\|XMODIFIERS\)'
ECORE_IMF_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
XMODIFIERS=@im=none
```

And here is the output of `xev` when pressing <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xd9, subw 0x0, time 29204065, (131,637), root:(135,656),
    state 0x10, keycode 34 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xd9, subw 0x0, time 29204135, (131,637), root:(135,656),
    state 0x10, keycode 34 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xd9, subw 0x0, time 29204545, (131,637), root:(135,656),
    state 0x10, keycode 24 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
    root 0xd9, subw 0x0, time 29204614, (131,637), root:(135,656),
    state 0x10, keycode 24 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```